# How Can get input from MDTextField when i press Enter

Tags: python, input, kivy, kivymd

i need to get input from user and store it in list and scrollview show it, in code below i tryed to make input field with kv language and i assign id to it so i can store input , problem is i need user press enter and will get his input on scroll List below inputField i need help here

***> main.py***

```
    from kivy.core import window
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
    from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
    
    Window.size = (480,800)

    class INSPECTOR(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        screen = Builder.load_file('layout.kv')
        #input = self.root.ids.get_barcode.string
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        self.barcode = self.root.ids.barcode.text
        self.list = []
            

    def on_enter(self):
        self.list.append(self.barcode)
        for i in range(self.list):
            self.item = OneLineListItem(text=f"{self.list[i]}")
            self.root.ids.contaniner.add_widget(self.item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    INSPECTOR().run()
```

> ***layout.kv***

```
Screen:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'INSPECTOR'
        elevation:5

    MDTextField:
        id: barcode
        hint_text: "Scan"
        mode: "rectangle"
        icon_right:'barcode-scan'
        focus: True
        padding_top:
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        width: 400
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "Enter text"
        on_text: app.on_enter

    GridLayout:
        padding:50
        cols:1
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: contaniner
```

I want to know how to make an entry field that stores data when I press the Enter button

Answer (score 0):

The `on_text` event for the `MDTextField` fires every time the text changes. If you can use a single line `MDTextField`, then you can modify the `kv` as:

```
    MDTextField:
        id: barcode
        hint_text: "Scan"
        mode: "rectangle"
        icon_right:'barcode-scan'
        focus: True
        padding_top:
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
        width: 400
        required: True
        helper_text_mode: "on_error"
        helper_text: "Enter text"
        multiline: False  # single line
        on_text_validate: app.on_enter()  # call on_enter() when enter is pressed
```

Note the `multiline` and `on_text_validate` attributes.

Then the `on_enter()` method can be:

```
def on_enter(self):
    text = self.root.ids.barcode.text
    self.list.append(text)
    for i in range(len(self.list)):
        self.item = OneLineListItem(text=f"{self.list[i]}")
        self.root.ids.contaniner.add_widget(self.item)
```

Comment: it work and pushed widget to scrollview but didnt get text from inputfield

Comment: The line: `text = self.root.ids.barcode.text` gets the text from the `MDTextField`. Add a `print()` statement right after that to see what the text is.